# Reproducible saveRDS with environments

Tags: r, r-package, binary-reproducibility

I am building an R package and using `data-raw` and `data` to store a library of pre-defined `RxODE` models. This works very well.

However, the resulting `.rda` files change at every generation. Some models contain an R environment, and the serialization seems to contain a 'creation time' timestamp. This means every time the `data/` directory is regenerated, all files have changed...

**Is there some way to modify the serialization of an R environment to be reproducible?**

```
storeFile <- function(file) {
  env <- new.env()
  fun <- function(x) {x+3}
  environment(fun) <- env

  save('fun', file = file, ascii=TRUE)
}

storeFile('fileA.rda')
storeFile('fileB.rda')
message("Files are identical? ", identical(readLines('fileA.rda'), readLines('fileB.rda')) )
```

Comment: `new.env()` does not do the same thing when called twice, it creates a different environment, so your are saving different objects.

Answer (score 0):

very interesting question. There is an oddly behaviour:

```
storeFile <- function(file) {

  env <- new.env()
  fun <- function(x) {x+3}
  environment(fun) <- env

  save.image(file = file, ascii=TRUE)
}


storeFile('fileA.rda')
storeFile('fileB.rda')
message("Files are identical? ", identical(readLines('fileA.rda'), readLines('fileB.rda')) )


storeFile('fileA.rda')
storeFile('fileB.rda')
message("Files are identical? ", identical(readLines('fileA.rda'), readLines('fileB.rda')) )
```

My output is FALSE in the first identical but TRUE in the second. I do not clearly know why. 
Also I'm using save.image instead of save, so I do not know if it suits you!
Best!